# ClickOnce deployment: Why is there a 404 error on a URL which, if pasted into the browser, has no problems?

Tags: c#, vb.net, iis, visual-studio-2019, clickonce

I've published a half dozen apps written in C# using Visual Studio and ClickOnce to IIS running on my development PC but with one solution, which has a VB.NET main project and  C# class library, I'm getting an error message:  `Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed`.

The app is being launched via the **launch** link in the `publish.htm` file. Edge asks if I want to open it.  I click the OPEN button and the app is downloaded and the progress bar finishes and then there's the popup error message saying that the URL could not be parsed.

When I check the IIS logs it looks like this:

```
https://mypc/apps/foo/publish.htm 404 0 2 1
```

But if I paste the URL `https://mypc/apps/foo/publish.htm` into the Edge browser's address box, the page is opened in the browser without any issue:

So I don't understand the 404 error. The other apps, all of which can be launched without issue from their publish.htm page, are published in identical manner, to the same website location in sibling folders:

```
https://mypc/apps/foo2/publish.htm
```

The structural differences between this solution and the others are

1. the EXE project of this problem solution is written in VB.NET and there is another project in the solution written in C# that produces a class library and
2. in the problem solution on the EXE's Properties->Application tab, there are two buttons:  `Assembly Information`  and `View Windows Settings` whereas on all the other working apps there is no `View Windows Settings` button on that tab and
3. on the working applications there is a `Manifest` option on the Application tab, where one of the choices is "embed manifest with default settings" whereas on the VB project's Application tab there is no such Manifest dropdown visible.

I hope there is some clue in these details.  What am I missing and how to proceed to troubleshoot this?

Comment: What kind of project is it? Also, adding an image to your post may be helpful.

Comment: The output type is is `Windows Application`.  What would the image show? I'm not sure what would be helpful to see.

Comment: Images of what you see,  such as what you describe in #2.

Comment: IIS is a network server to host web applicaion. As far as I know, it cannot support for windows application.

Comment: @Bruce Zhang:  IIS is used to install and launch the application, not to host it.

Comment: Can you show any images about how this error happened?